# dataDetectorTypes slow to respond (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've set my webview's dataDetectorType to UIDataDetectorTypeAll:

```
_webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

This works great on initialization, however, when I type in a link, it doesn't recognize right away, only if I move the cursor to a different spot will it detect the link, usually 3 seconds later.

How do I detect a link/email/phone number immediately after typing it into a webview, instead of having to move the cursor?

Comment: did you had any chance to fix this? I am having same issue

Comment: nope, unfortunately